# Read Data for the current user?

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

Hello I would like to know how to read data for the current user logged in and how to retrieve the data.
The first code up to updateName function is in another viewController. The function updateName is in another ViewController. 
I put the data under "User" and then have 2 key value pairs called Firstname = SomeData, LastName = SomeData in Firebase RealTimeDatabse, how can I access the only data for the current User logged in. 
I updated the code to give credit is the called frank,
The problem is that it doesn't read data into it and gives a null value, I know why because since the user is creating it user account the uid is null.
So how do i save the name of the user when the user is creating it account and call it back for its profile 
can you please help me 
Thanks for the Help in advance

```
        let nameDB = Database.database().reference().child("User")
    let nameDictionary = ["FirstName" : fullName.text!, "LastName" : lastName.text!]   
    let uid = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid
    Auth.auth().createUser(withEmail: email.text!, password: password1) { (userInformation, someKindOfError) in

            if someKindOfError != nil {
                print(someKindOfError!)
            } else {
                //success

             nameDB.child(uid!).setValue(nameDictionary) {
                    //error 
                    (error, reference) in
                    if error != nil{
                        print(error!)
                    } else  {
                        print("Name saved Sucessful")

                    }
                }
                print("Registration successful!!")

            }
        }

   //Different viewController
   func updateName() {

    let userID = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid

    let fullName = Database.database().reference().child("User").child(userID!)



    fullName.observeSingleEvent(of: .value) { (snapShot) in

       print("Enter snapShot")
        if let snapShotValue = snapShot.value as? [String : String]{

            print("Entering to grab the data")
            let first = snapShotValue["FirstName"] //as? String
            let last =  snapShotValue["LastName"] //as? String
            print(first, last)

            self.fullName.text = "\(first) \(last)"

        }
    }
```

Data structure:

```
 {
"User" : {
"fTKigbhqdVfis9SFk7ofsq1k9Gw1" : {
  "FirstName" : "Alfred",
  "LastName" : "case"
}
 }

 }
```

Comment: The code looks fine at first glance. What doesn't work about it? Specifically: what line doesn't do what you expect it to do? Also note that it'd be useful if your question includes the JSON that you're reading (as text, no screenshots please). You can get this by clicking the "Export JSON" link in the overflow menu (⠇) on your [Firebase Database console](https://console.firebase.google.com/project/_/database/data).

Comment: Where it says snapShotValue = snapShot.value as... that whole thing doesn’t execute by the way I’m new to firebase, I want to get the current user first name and last name

Comment: How did you determine it doesn't execute? Note that data is loaded asynchronously, so you can't step into that callback with a debugger. Instead set a breakpoint on the `if let snapShotValue` line to see if it gets hit, or put a `print` right before it

Comment: I did and nothing prints and if I take out .child(userID!) then prints nil nil

Comment: That sounds like there is no data under `User` in your database. Check the spelling, or update your question to include a snippet of the relevant JSON you're trying to read (as text, no screenshots please). You can get this by clicking the "Export JSON" link in the overflow menu (⠇) on your [Firebase Database console](https://console.firebase.google.com/project/_/database/data).

Comment: Well the user have 2 key value pairs first one called firstname and last name and it does have data but don’t know why is not retrieving it

Comment: Don't describe your data structure, but *show* it by adding the JSON to your question please.

Comment: "User" : {
    "numbersHereGeneratedbyFirebaseJustPlacedWordForIt" : {
      "FirstName" : "name1",
      "LastName" : "lastname2"
    }
  }

Comment: here it is please help I really want it to work :)

Comment: Add your information directly to your question please. I did that for you now, but there's an edit link under it that you can click in the future. Next up: don't fake any data, but show exactly what you currently have that doesn't work. The `"numbersHereGeneratedbyFirebaseJustPlacedWordForIt"` is not what's really there, and it makes it hard for us to determine if you appllied the change from my answer correctly. Don't worry about sharing the UID of push ID as neither of those are security credentials. They're merely identifiers meant for sharing.

Comment: okay now I know thanks, how can i retrieve that data to my iOS app

Comment: Why is it saying null if their is data inside?

Comment: Right now your question still contains the code we started with, which I answer already on why it won't work. I already told you why I can't help you further without seeing the actual JSON, with the actual key and not something you made up. If it's easier, you can also show the updated code of how you *now* write the data, although it's really a new question by now, as the initial reason it didn't work is what I answer below already.

Comment: Okay, I found out sometime it works, so you want everything can I just blur the data then

Comment: I have pasted the key

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're writing the data for a user like this:

```
let nameDB = Database.database().reference().child("User")
nameDB.childByAutoId().setValue(nameDictionary)
```

And then you read it with this:

```
let fullName = Database.database().reference().child("User").child(userID!)
fullName.observeSingleEvent(of: .value) { (snapShot
  ...
```

If you look carefully the paths are different. You write to `/User/$autoId` and read from `/User/$uid`. A user's UID is not the same as an ID that is generated by `childByAutoId`.

You probably want to write to:

```
let nameDB = Database.database().reference().child("User")
let uid = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid
nameDB.child(uid).setValue(nameDictionary)
```

Comment: Is it cool to put this nameDB.child(uid!).setValue(nameDictionary) {
                        //error , and the refenerce of the data that was saved
                        (error, reference) in
                        if error != nil{
                            print(error!)
                        } else  {
                            print("Name saved Sucessful")
                            
                        }
                    }

Comment: Thanks for helping me :)

Comment: And yes, your code looks fine. I just removed the completion handler from my answer to keep it short.

Comment: But it still won’t display the first name and last name

Comment: Hey @frank where it says nameDB.child(uid!).setValue(nameDictionary) i put it where the user can sign up for the app, when the user taps on create button then is show an error here why is it?

Comment: when the user created an account and never made one please help

Comment: If you have an error, what is the exact error message and stack trace.

Comment: This is what it says: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

Comment: the uid = (String?) nil maybe because the user is creating a new account and its looking for a uid which does not exist because the user is creating its account